# Three trier Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write a linq query in C# that will return the list of customers who received all the items they ordered but can't figure it out

My database schema looks like this:
Table Name: Customers, primary field: CustomerId
Table Name: Orders, primary field: OrderId, foreign key: CustomerId
Table Name: OrderLineItems, primary field: LineItemId, foreign key: OrderId

The line items table also has a field called 'Status' where I indicate if this item has been 'Ordered', 'Backordered', 'Shipped', etc.

What I'm looking for is the list of customers with at least one order (I'm not interested in customers who haven't ordered anything), I am only interested in orders with at least one item (just in case someone creates an empty order without any items), and finally my last criteria is that all items must have a given status (say: 'Shipped' for instance).

If I was to write the SQL query, it would look something like this:

```
SELECT  c.*
  FROM  Customers c 
        INNER JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId
        INNER JOIN (SELECT oli.OrderId, COUNT(*) AS [NumberOfItems] FROM OrderLineItems oli WHERE oli.Status <> 'Shipped' GROUP BY oli.OrderId) items ON o.OrderId = items.OrderId
 WHERE  items.NumberOfItems = 0
```

(feel free to suggest a better SQL query, by the way, if you can think of a better way to get the data I'm looking for)

Ideally, I would get C# code that kinda looks like this:

```
var customers = from c in context.Customers
    where ...
    select c;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
customers.Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o => 
    o.OrderLineItems.Any() 
    && o.OrderLineItems.All(i => i.Status == requestedStatus)))
```

The `Orders.Any()` criterion is for your requirement "customers with at least one order";
the `OrderLineItems.Any()` criterion for "I am only interested in orders with at least one item", and the `OrderLineItems.All()` criterion for "all items must have a given status".